# Trouble connecting to MySQL database using my java code

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL using the following JAVA code.
However, I'm getting an SQLException (*connection cannot be established*)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class Jdbctest {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            // for establishing connection, cnn is object of connection
            final Connection cnn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.68.11.128:1521/orcl");
            System.out.println("connection to db");

        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is it Oracle or MySQL??

Comment: Look at the caught SQLException more closely and tell us e.g. about the exception message, i.e. call sxl.getMessage() and log / print it.

Answer (score 3):

You are providing the driver class and connection string of oracle database.
How can you connect with MySQL db.

Use the below tutorial for connecting with MySQL:-
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

To this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And this

```
Connection cnn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.68.11.128:1521/orcl");
```

To this

```
Connection cnn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:thin:@//192.68.11.128:1521/orcl", "Enter your database username", "Enter your database password");
```

This is all assumming of course your database is MySQL like you said above

Answer (score 0):

This class will help you connect to  mysql database. You have to change the database name and if your user is root and password is null then you  good to go, else  you have to change them also .

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class jdbcConnect {
    public static void main  (String args[]) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = null ;
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabasename","root","");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "We are Connected");
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}
    } 

}
```